# What is the most efficient way to get data from InfluxDB (v2) into polars?

Tags: python, influxdb, python-polars

I want to retrieve data from InfluxDB (self hosted, Version 2.0) and process it in python using polars. For communication I am using the [InfluxDBClient](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python) for InfluxDB v2. At the moment I am doing it using this:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
import polars
import os

load_dotenv()

client = InfluxDBClient(
    url=os.getenv("url"), token=os.getenv("token"), org=os.getenv("org"))

query_api = client.query_api()

flux_string = 'from(bucket: "test_bucket") |> range(start:-2y) |> drop(columns: ["_start","_stop"])'

data_frame = query_api.query_data_frame(flux_string)

polars_data = polars.from_pandas(data_frame)
```

For around 80 000 rows of data, this takes about 1 to 2 seconds (varies a bit). Is there a more efficient way of getting the data? This will be part of a web app for internal use, so I'd want to avoid any long processing times.

I also tried some of the other methods offered by the influxdb-client package, maybe there is some way to take some other output and get it into polars? Further info about the functions: [docs](https://influxdb-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#influxdb_client.QueryApi.query_csv)

| function | processing time | return type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `query_raw()` | 0,5 s | HTTPResponse object (converts to string) |
| `query_data_frame()` | 1,5 s | pandas DataFrame |
| `query_data_frame_stream()` | 0,6 s | generator object |
| `query_csv()` | 0,5 s | csv iterator |
| `query_stream()` | 0,7 s | generator object |

As always, thank you a lot for any help!